# How can I host host generated HTML documentation (AsyncAPI) in Vercel?

Tags: vercel, asyncapi

I am generating an HTML file from a .yaml file using AsyncAPI for documentation within my project - I want to host this documentation on Vercel, but *only* that file within my project using a GitHub action so that every time a change is pushed or a PR is merged it redeploys in Vercel. What is the best way to go about this?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to do this is a simple script that would be fired from Vercel context. When a new commit is committed, Vercel runs the given script to generate documentation and deploys the output of this generation.

So I would create a simple, private NodeJS package with the `@asyncapi/generator` and `@asyncapi/html-template` dependencies and then configure Vercel either through the UI on admin site or through the `vercel.js` file:

- `package.json`:

  ```json
  {
    "devDependencies": {
      "@asyncapi/generator": "^1.9.11",
      "@asyncapi/html-template": "^0.25.2"
    },
    "scripts": {
      "build": "./node_modules/.bin/asyncapi-generator {PATH_TO_SPEC} @asyncapi/html-template -o {OUTPUT_FOLDER} --force-write ...{OTHER_PARAMS}"
    }
  }
  ```
- `vercel.json`:

  ```json
  {
     "buildCommand": "npm run build",
     "outputDirectory": "{OUTPUT_FOLDER}"
  }
  ```

I haven't tested it, but I would go in that direction :) Of course the generated html file should be `index.html`.